# why when i use JPA bidirectional mapping one to one i can not persist entity from one direct

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, ejb

I use postgres db. I created two table is user and user_information, user has link to user_information:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
    id              NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('users_id'),
    password            TEXT NOT NULL,
    email               TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    phone               TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE USERS_INFORMATION(
    id      NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('users_information_id'),
    user_id     NUMERIC UNIQUE REFERENCES USERS(ID) NOT NULL,
    firs_name   TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    last_name   TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    SEX     TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    BIRTHDAY    DATE DEFAULT NULL
);
```

then i create jpa entity:
User:

```
@Entity

...

public class User implements Serializable {
    ...

    public User() {
    }

    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public UsersInformation getUsersInformation() {
        return this.usersInformation;
    }
}
```

and user_information:

```
@Entity
...
public class UsersInformation implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    ...

}
```

why i can create object user_information set in it object user end use persist(user_informtion) and it is work, but when i create user and set user_information in user and use persist(user) it is transaction exception? How i can fix it. I use JPA eclipselink, ejb like facade and glassfish.

Comment: Did you remember to set the object references in both directions? I mean call `setUserInformation(user)` and `setUser(userInfo)` on them accordingly?

Comment: thanks, it is working)

Comment: @coladict, please place your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To cascade-persist, you need to make sure both objects refer to each-other, by calling `userInfo.setUserInformation(user)` and `user.setUser(userInfo)` respectively on each of them before persisting. JPA doesn't fill in that blank automatically, because your data model (while in almost all cases would be like this) does not necessarily have to be linear. The references may in fact zig-zag across several objects, if that's the best fit to your customer requirements.